# Calling href value in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could you please help me to call href value which is changing every time. Below is the code for your reference:

```
<a href="http://click1.clickrouter.com/redirect?token=a2258079c24c4c50a56b6b1ffb75d6e2&amp;url=https%3A//u2720269.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click%3Fupn%3DRuyytLyMzocaRpUHe9Z1QCe0o5SY-2BbrKEnssVFEC2nFM466GSvGSbWIPZo2Xpeyn-2F0QAElxl7c7bwKXcdymgtcm9RjSv0ivZZXtv2n8DKYnWlKkQroF-2BEDfllIkFXTyS20elE5OuRKl3wPQBh0E76Nj-2BQArVjoxEfD4fUEVLUkI-3D_5SnvLCTBgVqPjimwaiavQTZsy6v0FmqoHbMtHV6MMfx-2FCs1eGI1d4Bexl3L2zftKx-2FvaNVM5Uwe7h0ZTAHWuyNOLa3UkvoB3WljrbHWRfL2LCArojXFquIo8ltK6-2BRTtQyTe7jpRGsBnxQUyyEhyT7KGbgdF0T-2BqZ01kZMoHzklNV-2BOkV6gSY0NZvlW0iq6LXowmHug1UsgSa4LTxTH0elpPaEGQhdEPe0zJsuoYSBQ-3D" target="_other" rel="nofollow">click here</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please give link.

Comment: <a href="http://click1.clickrouter.com/redirect?token=a2258079c24c4c50a56b6b1ffb75d6e2&amp;url=https%3A//u2720269.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click%3Fupn%3DRuyytLyMzocaRpUHe9Z1QCe0o5SY-2j-2BQArVjoxEfD4fUEVLUkI-3D_5SnvLCTBgVqPjimwaiavQTZsy6v0FmqoHbMtHV6MMfx-2FCs1eGI1d4Bexl3L2zftKx-2FvaNVM5Uwe7h0ZTAHWuyNOLa3UkvoB3WljrbHWRfL2LCArojXFquIo8ltK6-2BRTtQyTe7jpRGsBnxQUyyEhyT7KGbgdF0T-2BqZ01kZMoHzklNV-2BOkV6gSY0NZvlW0iq6LXowmHug1UsgSa4LTxTH0elpPaEGQhdEPe0zJsuoYSBQ-3D" target="_other" rel="nofollow">click here</a>

Comment: you want to get all link or only this one ?

Comment: i suggest to use this code `String strLinkHref = driver.findElement(By.linkText("click here")).getAttribute("href");`

Comment: if above works then let me know, i will post full answer

Comment: actually, i want to click this link after this it is redirecting into a new tab and for that page also URL is changed every time.

Comment: Can you share application link ?

Comment: sorry but its in vm machine. Not possible for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158470/discussion-between-sagar007-and-ajay-kumar).

Comment: please share your above code let me try with this

Comment: No one can not write code without any application. But still I think your question is little confusing now. You want to get herf attribute value. That will get by this line of code. `String strLinkHref = driver.findElement(By.linkText("click here")).getAttribute("href");`. For more details please write your question more clarify way.

Comment: @ajaykumar, did you try my answer? If it was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your comment, Test cases needed the `href` (link) attribute value. So code can be written by this way :

```
 String strLinkHref = driver.findElement(By.linkText("click here")).getAttribute("href");
```

or

```
String strLinkHref = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='click here']")).getAttribute("href");
```

**Note : here you can store in String and print. It will get link dynamically every time.**

---

**If test case needed to open it, then you can use :**

```
driver.get(strLinkHref);
```

---

**If you require to move to TAB window, Please use below code :**

```
     String handle= driver.getWindowHandle(); 

     System.out.println(handle); 

     // Click on the Button "New Message Window" 

     driver.findElement(By.name("New Message Window")).click(); 

     // Store and Print the name of all the windows open 

     Set handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 

     System.out.println(handles); 

     // Pass a window handle to the other window 

     for (String handle1 : driver.getWindowHandles()) { 

     System.out.println(handle1); 

      driver.switchTo().window(handle1); 
      currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
      System.out.println(currentURL);

     } 

     // Closing Pop Up window
      driver.close();
```

[Reference](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/)

Comment: Please verify above answer. If I have solved your problem accept it. So other persons as well understand.